32 bit Multiplication synthesis in Quartus in VHDL on cyclone V FPGA
I encountered a strange behavior while simulating my ALU. I designed a 32-bit ALU in VHDL to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, OR, AND, and XOR operations. During simulation, all operations execute correctly except for multiplication.
Could you help me understand why Quartus is unable to synthesize the multiplication block? Previously, I created a very fast multiplication unit for 4-bit inputs using full adders, and I expected that the standard library would handle this for a 32-bit unit. However, it seems I am missing something.
Thank you for your assistance.
VHDL code:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity ALU is
    Port (
        A       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        B       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        ALU_Sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
        Result  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0)
    );
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is
    signal Mul_Result : unsigned(63 downto 0);  -- Intermediate signal for multiplication result
begin
    process(A, B, ALU_Sel)
    begin
        case ALU_Sel is
            when "000" =>  -- Addition
                Result <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(A), 64) + resize(unsigned(B), 64));
            when "001" =>  -- Subtraction
                Result <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(A), 64) - resize(unsigned(B), 64));
            when "010" =>  -- Multiplication
                Mul_Result <= unsigned(A) * unsigned(B);
                Result <= std_logic_vector(Mul_Result);
            when "011" =>  -- Division
                if B /= "00000000000000000000000000000000" then
                    Result <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(A) / unsigned(B), 64));
                else
                    Result <= (others => '0');  -- Division by zero results in zero
                end if;
            when "100" =>  -- AND
                Result <= "00000000000000000000000000000000" & (A and B);
            when "101" =>  -- OR
                Result <= "00000000000000000000000000000000" & (A or B);
            when "110" =>  -- XOR
                Result <= "00000000000000000000000000000000" & (A xor B);
            when others =>
                Result <= (others => '0');  -- Default case
        end case;
    end process;
end Behavioral;

Testbench vhdl:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity ALU_tb is
end ALU_tb;

architecture Behavioral of ALU_tb is

    -- Component Declaration for the ALU
    component ALU
        Port (
            A       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
            B       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
            ALU_Sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
            Result  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    -- Inputs
    signal A       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal B       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal ALU_Sel : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    -- Outputs
    signal Result  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);

begin

    -- Instantiate the ALU
    uut: ALU Port map (
            A => A,
            B => B,
            ALU_Sel => ALU_Sel,
            Result => Result
        );

    -- Stimulus process
    stim_proc: process
    begin
        -- Test Addition
        A <= "00000000000000000000000000000101"; -- 5
        B <= "00000000000000000000000000000111"; -- 7
        ALU_Sel <= "000";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Test Subtraction
        ALU_Sel <= "001";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Test Multiplication
        ALU_Sel <= "010";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Test Division
        ALU_Sel <= "011";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Test AND
        ALU_Sel <= "100";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Test OR
        ALU_Sel <= "101";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Test XOR
        ALU_Sel <= "110";
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- End simulation
        wait;
    end process;

end Behavioral;



The signal value of Mul_Result isn't updated in the same simulation cycle it's assigned. There needs to be an intervening wait statement.  You could eliminate Mul_Result and Result <= std_logic_vector ( unsigned(A) * unsigned(B) ); assigning the std_logic_vector type converted multiplier product to Result directly. Simply putting Mul_Result in the process sensitivity list might work but isn't necessary. Otherwise  Mul_Result could be a a variable declared in the process instead of a signal.

This isn't a synthesis issue at all; it's a simulation issue.
For some reason, you introduced an intermediate signal Mul_Result for multiplication, rather than doing it in one statement like all of the other ALU functions. Furthermore, this signal is not listed in the process sensitivity list for the ALU.
Therefore, the process is only triggered once, when ALU_Sel changes. The simulator updates both Mul_Result and Result, but the second assignment uses the "old" value of Mul_Result rather than the value just computed. Since there was no initialization of Mul_Result, this shows as unknown.
If you had listed Mul_Result in the sensitivity list, then the process would have immediately been evaluated a second time, and the value of Result would have been as expected. Or if you had eliminated the extra signal and done the multiplication in a single step, it would have worked as well.
